# Applying animation in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

Is there any way I can implement the animation like 
https://codemyui.com/circular-water-fill-loading-animation/ in Xamarin.forms?

Comment: You can have a look at Lottie  https://airbnb.design/lottie/ and the Xamarin wrapper https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin to handle svg animations.

If not I'm afraid you will have to code it yourself. Maybe with the help of SkiaSharp https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/skiasharp/

Comment: Lottie can be used in Xamarin Forms for Android, iOS (and probably UWP) by wrapping control to Xamarin Forms. But Lottie.SkiaSharp would be great.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way I can implement the animation like ...

The short answer is; Yes.

The longer answer; It depends upon what you really need, only you can answer that.

A "quick way" (at least for me) is to use the Xamarin.Forms' `WebView` and embed the html/svg/css/JScript into native application projects and setup a javascript interface to control the percentage completion (the `water.style.transform` element).

- https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithWebview/

You could, of course, re-implement it using something like SkiaSharp, Lottie, etc and create a cross-platform Forms' control, or implement it as a "native" control on each platform.

Note: I'm a big fan of Lottie and would personally take that approach, but they do not support native UWP. Currently supported is iOS, Android, Web.

I edited the colors, etc. on that PEN sample you linked to and added the html/js/css to a Forms' solution, setup a JS interface and the results work in a Forms' WebView (iOS' UIWebView and Android's WebView, did not test UWP Edge, but it should work fine):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The Lottie is my preferred, but you can use a animation with the Nuget XamAnimation. It most hard to create but it's so good too.